# Windows forms web browser control and Javascript-altered DOM

Tags: javascript, windows, winforms, browser

The windows forms web browser control supports Javascript; this Javascript can make changes to the DOM. However, when I call the DocumentText property, I always get the unmodified HTML. Is there any way to get the HTML *after* modification?

Comment: Wait wait, I don't understand. You have form controls, and you want to get their contents, or you have forms which modify the DOM, and you want the result? Anyway, please share the code you currently have to better illustrate your problem.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I have a HTMLEmbeddedBrowser object that's loading a page. That page has javascript on it, and the javascript alters the class attribute of some of the elements of the page so they're styled differently. I can see the style I want, but when I fetch out the DocumentText, I get the page as written, before javascript modifies it.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I hadn't had a chance yet. Yes, that does look like what I want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just do: `webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml`

Answer (score 0):

when you modifiy the html doc, is it form elements, or other types of element.

one thing i noticed during debugging is that when i use the setAttribute for input form and then use `webbrowser1.document.innerText`, i get the modified doc returned.

my suggestion is that you either set the html doc propert you are modifying throug code first, and or use `webbrowser1.document.body.innerText`

Comment: I'm not modifying it myself. I'm loading a page that has javascript in it that modifies the CSS class of certain elements.